# Capturing mouse click locations in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm using the MATLAB built-in function [`getpts`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/getpts.html) to allow a user to put points on the figure then apply bezier curve on these points. The problem is that when the user clicks for the first time, the place where the mouse is first clicked is not the same as the point that is displayed by `getpts`. What is the issue here?

At this image you can see the red star for the real place of clicked mouse and at the second image you can see the result point after clicked!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Show us the code you wrote. We don't know what the problem is unless we see what you wrote.

Comment: I updated my post with two pictures you can see that

Comment: Those images do not show what getpts gives you......

Comment: @AnderBiguri This is actually a legitimate question, albeit presented very poorly. Check my answer below to see what is happening.

Comment: @rayryeng See above comment since I can't ping you both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue that you are describing is because you have [automatic resizing of the axes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html#inputarg_mode) enabled (`axis auto` which is the default). When you first display an `axes`, the xrange is `[0, 1]` and the yrange is `[0, 1]`. As soon as you plot something, the axes limits resize to automatically fit the new data.

So if we take a look at where you initially clicked, it's the lower left-hand corner of your axes.

Now look at the x,y coordinates that you're plotting and that were returned by `getpts`. If you consider that the axes limits were `[0,1]` for x and `[0,1]` for y, then you'll realize that the x,y coordinates that are returned *were* in the  lower left hand corner *exactly* where your star is.

The issue is that as soon as you plot that point `plot(x,y)`, the axes limits *shift* to place this new point in the center of the axes (note the x and y axes limits in the figure you've posted). As a result, it *appears* as though it's in the wrong place when in fact it's the correct place and the *view* has changed. You can watch this change in axes limits yourself by watching the xticklabels and yticklabels as you plot the new point.

The easiest way to fix this (and to ensure that this is actually what's happening) is to use the [`axis`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html) command to disable the automatic axes resizing prior to calling `getpts`.

```
axis manual
```

After this, [x](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlim.html) and [y limits](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ylim.html) of the axes will only be changed if you manually change them and you shouldn't have any more issues like the one that you have described.

The entire code that should work is.

```
fig = figure();
hax = axes('Parent', fig);
axis(hax, 'manual')
[x,y] = getpts();
```

Comment: I tried to make that 
>> hold on
>> axis([0 10 0 10])
>> axis manual
>> [x,y] = getpts(axes)
but it's the same issue , ok the axes range is changed but the issue about initial click is the same !

Comment: @AlaaKhaled please run the last part of my post that I just updated. You shouldn't have any issues running that.

Comment: Thanks, it's working very good :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `CurrentPoint` property of figure or axes to do what you want.
in axes object :
Location of last mouse click, specified as a 2-by-3 array in the axes coordinate system. The `CurrentPoint` property contains the coordinates of two points defined by the location of the pointer at the last mouse click, with respect to the requested axes.

If the click is within the axes in orthogonal projection, then the two points lie on the line that is perpendicular to the plane of the screen and that passes through the pointer. This is true for both 2-D and 3-D views.

The 3-D coordinates are the points, in the axes coordinate system, where this line intersects the front and back surfaces of the axes volume (which is defined by the axes x, y, and z limits).

The returned matrix is of the form:

```
[xfront yfront zfront
xback  yback  zback]
```

The first row defines the point nearest to the camera position. The second row specified the point furthest from the camera position.

If the click is outside the axes in orthogonal projection, but within the figure, the returned values are:

`Back point` — Point in the plane of the camera target (which is perpendicular to the viewing axis).

`Front point` — Point in the camera position plane (which is perpendicular to the viewing axis).

These points lie on a line that passes through the pointer and is perpendicular to the camera target and camera position planes.

The values of the current point when using perspective projection can be different from the same point in orthographic projection because the shape of the axes volume can be different.

Clicking outside of the axes volume in perspective projection returns the front point as the current camera position at all times. Only the back point updates with the coordinates of a point that lies on a line extending from the camera position through the pointer and intersecting the camera target at that point.

and for figure object :
Location of the last button click in this figure, returned as a two-element vector. The `CurrentPoint` property value is measured from the lower left corner of the figure window, in units determined by the Units property. MATLAB updates this property whenever a user presses the mouse button while the pointer is in the figure window.

If a user selects a point in the figure, and you use the values returned by the `CurrentPoint` property to plot that point, there can be differences in the position due to round-off errors.

for example

```
a=figure
plot(1:100)
location=a.CurrentPoint
```

Comment: This does not address the user's question at all. He isn't asking *how* to get the current point, but rather why the built-in `getpts` puts the point in the seeminly incorrect location.

Comment: @M.NozariPak Thanks for your answer I will try this option also to see all functions about it